# Identifying a game: Wizard Tower Defense card based game

Tags: identify-this-game

I recall playing this one back in the 80s-90s.  You played a Wizard defending his tower from various enemies, one of whom was definitely called Lord Mort.  It was card based and multiplayer where the players could help or hinder if I recall correctly.  Similar to the way Munchkin plays.

Any idea?  Thanks!

Comment: Defending a tower reminds me of Castle Panic, but I don't remember that game having any wizards.

Comment: Castle Panic had much higher production values. :)  The game I am looking for was simple black and white line drawings and I want to say it came in a ziplock bag.